# SAML payload url encoding after Base64

Tags: spring-saml, opensaml

In a IDP initiated environment the payload is not able to decode it.
Getting exception in  `decoder.decode(samlContext);`

So after analysing I found that the payload is encrypted with URL encoding after Base64 encoding.
Any way there if I can consume this payload and decode it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue I was facing due to some copy paste issue, now solved.